# What happens when you call a method in a constructor from a subclass?

Tags: java

I have a subclass that I want to initialize a variable in the constructor and the best way to do it is using a method. In my case, I have a parent class called `ThreeDigitInteger`, and I have a subclass of the parent class called `ThreeDigitCode` In the subclass, I have a private boolean called `isValid`, and to check if it is valid, I have a method in the class called `public boolean isValid()`. Is it possible to call the method in the constructor? Keep in mind, there is no `isValid()` method in the parent class. But if there was, would that affect the outcome?

```
public class ThreeDigitInteger
{
    //Constructors and Methods
}

public class ThreeDigitCode extends ThreeDigitInteger
{
    private boolean isValid;
    private integer = value;
    public ThreeDigitCode (int aValue)
    {
        value = aValue;
        isValid = isValid();
    }

    public boolean isValid()
    {
        //Method implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not try and see?

Comment: Please post **complete and  formatted** code. Your code is not readable!

Comment: That code will not compile. `private integer = value;` is entirely wrong. Should be `private int value;` --- And what's the point of the `isValid` field? Presumably the `isValid()` method won't use it, so what's the point?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please [see the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Also, I edited the text of your question adding formats to methods and variables. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to call the method from the constructor, it will behave exactly as if it was called from anywhere else.

If there is a method called isValid() in the superclass, the subclass will override that method.